# Derivation of a stochastic Navier-Stokes equation with multiplicative noise

Tags: partial-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, mathematical-physics, stochastic-analysis, fluid-dynamics

Most of the literature is targeting a special stochastic version of the deterministic Navier-Stokes equation without giving a derivation of the considered equation.

I'm searching for such a derivation. Moreover, the derivation should be based on the assumption that the trajectories of the fluid particles are perturbed (in contrast to the assumption that the velocity fluid is perturbed - which leads to additive noise).

I've searched for a long time and I've read many papers, but the only derivation I've found is [*Stochastic Navier-Stokes Equations for Turbulent Flows*](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/S0036141002409167). However, the derivation is somehow vague and they impose special assumptions on the deterministic resolved velocity.

So, I would be very happy, if someone knows a book or paper with a detailed derivation.